# display not changing despite variables being changed on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to write a program where after a user enters text and clicks a button, the text becomes a label and the button text is changed. My code is:

```
# Imports

import os, sys

import tkinter

"""
Tkinter program 1
text box + button + label
"""


# Button Entry

def enter(inputtedinfo, randvar, EnterMessage):

    randvar = inputtedinfo.get()

    EnterMessage = "Submitted!"

# Main Function

def main():

    something = tkinter.Tk()

    something.title("My First Tkinter Window")

    something.geometry("600x400")

    randvar = ""

    EnterMessage = "Enter"

    inputtedinfo = tkinter.StringVar()

    userLabel = tkinter.Label(something, text = randvar)

    userEntry = tkinter.Entry(something, textvariable = inputtedinfo)
    
    userButton = tkinter.Button(something, text = EnterMessage, command = enter(inputtedinfo, randvar, EnterMessage))

    userEntry.grid(row=0,column=0)

    userLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

    userButton.grid(row=0,column=2)

    something.mainloop()

    sys.exit(0)

if(__name__ == "__main__"):

    main()
```

The user input works, but clicking the button does nothing despite the fact that it is supposed to change the variables for the button and label displays. Did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: `command=enter(...)` will execute `enter(...)` immediately and assign `None` to `command` option.  So when the button is clicked, nothing will happen.

Comment: More than that. this is not how Python variables work.  The `EnterMessage` in `enter` has nothing to do with `EnterMessage` in `main`.  You're passing the VALUE of that variable, but it's not a pointer; you can't change the value of `EnterMessage` in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

The `command` argument takes the name of a function. If you write the complete call with arguments, it's not the name of the function but whatever is returned by this exact function call. So, your button will not work. It will have the command `None`.

In order to do what you want to do, you have to make the `StringVar()`s accessible to the function you are calling. So, you can both get the contents of the entry and change the values of the button and the label. To do this, best add the string variables and the widgets as attributes to the toplevel you already created (`something`). So, they stay available to all functions and you can get and change information:

```
# Button Entry

def enter():

    something.randvar.set(something.inputtedinfo.get())

    something.userButton["text"] = "Submitted!"

# Main Function

def main():

    global something

    something = tkinter.Tk()

    something.title("My First Tkinter Window")

    something.geometry("600x400")

    something.randvar = tkinter.StringVar()

    something.randvar.set("")

    EnterMessage = "Enter"

    something.inputtedinfo = tkinter.StringVar()

    userLabel = tkinter.Label(something, textvariable = something.randvar)

    something.userEntry = tkinter.Entry(something, textvariable = something.inputtedinfo)
    
    something.userButton = tkinter.Button(something, text = EnterMessage, command = enter)

    something.userEntry.grid(row=0,column=0)

    userLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

    something.userButton.grid(row=0,column=2)

    something.mainloop()


if(__name__ == "__main__"):

    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code:

- assign string to `textvariable`, should use `StringVar` instead
- `command=enter(...)` will execute `enter(...)` immediately and then assign `None` to `command` option, should use `lambda` instead
- updating strings inside `enter()` does not automatically update the label and the button, should use `.set()` on the `StirngVar` instead

Below is modified code:

```py
def enter(inputtedinfo, randvar, EnterMessage):
    # used .set() to update StringVar
    randvar.set(inputtedinfo.get())
    EnterMessage.set("Submitted!")

def main():
    something = tkinter.Tk()
    something.title("My First Tkinter Window")
    something.geometry("600x400")
    randvar = tkinter.StringVar()  # changed to StringVar()
    EnterMessage = tkinter.StringVar(value="Enter") # changed to StringVar()
    inputtedinfo = tkinter.StringVar()
    userLabel = tkinter.Label(something, textvariable=randvar) # used textvariable instead of text option
    userEntry = tkinter.Entry(something, textvariable=inputtedinfo)
    userButton = tkinter.Button(something, textvariable=EnterMessage, command=lambda: enter(inputtedinfo, randvar, EnterMessage))
    userEntry.grid(row=0,column=0)
    userLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)
    userButton.grid(row=0,column=2)
    something.mainloop()
```